# WebGL matrix depth not working properly

Tags: matrix, webgl, depth

I'm very new to WebGL, but I'm getting close at understanding the basics.

I'm following the instructions in [Jacob Seidelin's book](http://blog.nihilogic.dk/2011/12/my-book-is-now-available.html) where he explains some of the basics.
I tried rebuilding one of his examples (which is not directly explained in the book).

For some reason the depth in the uModelView matrix doesn't work in my application. I also don't get any errors using the WebGLDebugUtils.

When I set the `z` property of the uModelView matrix to 0 the front face of the cube fills up the screen. Since I worked with `-1` to `1` in the vertices.

**Here is my source code: [removed]**

The shaders are located in the index.html, be they shouldn't be the problem.

I'm using [gl-matrix](https://github.com/toji/gl-matrix) for the matrix transformations.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not using the mat4.perspective correct. Checkout the documentation:

https://github.com/toji/gl-matrix/blob/master/gl-matrix.js#L1722

You should either add the matrix as the last parameter (this is the preferred way since this does not allocate any new object):

```
mat4.perspective(fov, aspect, near, far, matrix);
```

or assign it to the matrix:

```
matrix = mat4.perspective(fov, aspect, near, far);
```